# ActionCable channel not getting called on broadcasting message in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

First of all very new to the ActionCable feature. I have been following the tutorial here: https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/push-notifications-with-actioncable

Created a channel called `web_notifications_channel` and web_notifications_channel.rb:

```
class WebNotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "web_notifications_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

web_notifications_channel.js:

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("WebNotificationsChannel", {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    console.log(`wtf`)
    
  }
});
```

Nothing shows in console.

Changed the adapter settings to redis in cable.yml in order to request from console:

```
development:
  adapter: redis

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: community_rails_production
```

Running console command:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'web_notifications_channel', 'You have visited the welcome page.'
```

I get response as:

```
Broadcasting to web_notifications_channel: "You have visited the welcome page."
 => 0
```

But my `received` method never gets called!! I am getting nuts here as cannot understand what is happening!! I have checked some similar questions but none of them helped me.

PS: I have added the gem for redis and started redis from my console.

Comment: Haha, I was having the same issue. I'm still not sure if it's working 100% or not. There's an issue with ActionCable and its implementation. Start by upgrading to rails 6, try logging redis's console ( to see if it's saving there ) and pray that it will work :-p

Comment: I am right in the middle of implementing a feature, too much to handle this sh**. @RocKhalil. My rails is already 6 but what to log in redis console

Comment: I know right !! It took me 2-3 days to know that it's a rails 5.2 issue; upgraded to rails 6 to see if it's solved; it works something and sometimes it just doesn't propagate for some reason ! I'm thinking of switching to socket.io and a node server instead of ActionCable

Comment: I don't even have a redis logfile generated by default

Comment: Have you tried putting console.log statements in the `connected` and `disconnected` methods in your js file to see if they get executed?  If they don't show up, that could mean that you are not including the channel file in your application.js file (or similar, depending on your setup).

Answer (score 1):

The first param of the `create` method is an `object`, not a `string`

```js
consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "WebNotificationsChannel" }, {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    console.log(`wtf`)
    
  }
});
```

You can also check the connection in the `Network` tab in your devtool, filtered by `WS` to see if the connection is created successfully.

The `rails` server, or the `action cable` server (if you configure `action cable` to run as a standalone server) has the log as well to tell you if the connection is success or failed, with the details of the error, if any.